# how to make squirtle feet

Tags: modeling

I want to make squirtle feet using skin modifier and subdivision surface modifier. This is the result [image]

[image]

But the back of the feet looks flat. Is there any suggestion to solve this or is there a new way? This what I want
[image]

Comment: maybe it's not even possible with Skin modifier and you need to convert your edge to mesh in order to work its volume?

Comment: To add one more vertex ... ?

Comment: @vklidu I tried that too but the shape become flat square

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood - "became flat square" ? ... so I created answer, just to add some images what I meant ... probably better if you can add screen of desired result. Thanks

Comment: @vklidu Hi! I edited my question and add my desired result

Answer (score 6):

Try to add more vertices to better shape your object ...

[image]

[image]

To make bottom part flat (as seen in your reference) you can use **Boolean** modifier and "cut this part by Plane, but as you can see instep part is overlapping and I wasn't able to fix it (even with Remesh or Smooth modifier) to end up with something useful.

[image]

---

### EDIT

According to your reference ... It seems to me more easier to model this leg from Cylinder. Add Edge Loop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ...

[image]

*Extrude Individual Faces*

[image]

Adjust a bit to fit final shape and use *Crease* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> 1 (pink edges in screen) for edges that ...

[image]

... should stay sharp after *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]